# List in a List (Associations)

Tags: c#, forms, list, nested-lists

Trying to further my own understanding, I'm replication a simple database - and having trouble understanding the following;

I have 2 classes Town and People. A town owns many instances of People and are set like this;

```
    public class Town
{
    List<People> collectionOfPeople;

    public string townName { get; set; }

    public Town()
    {
        townName = "Cardiff";

        collectionOfPeople = new List<People>();
        collectionOfPeople.Add(new People("Daniel Smith"));
    }
}

    public class People
{

    public string name { get; set; }

    public People(string tmp_name)
    {
        name = tmp_name;
    }
}
```

Assuming what I've done is correct, Town has 1 value (Cardiff) and People also has one (Daniel Smith) or .. Daniel lives in Cardiff.

I am trying to display the names of People living within the Town.. to later cycle through them. (** = problem I think)

```
    private List<Town> townList;
    private List<Town.People> peopleList;              **

    private void ShowData()
    {
        // Add to Text Box based on current Record
        txt_town.Text = townList[0]).townName;
        txt_name.Text = peopleList[0].name;            **
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my changes. Provide public access modifier for collectionOfPeople in Town class.

```
public class Town
{
    public List<People> collectionOfPeople;
    public string townName { get; set; }
}
```

After that, you can access People instance within Town. Something like this:

```
private List<Town> townList = new List<Town>();    
private void ShowData()
{
    // Add to Text Box based on current Record
    txt_town.Text = townList[0].townName;
    txt_name.Text = townList[0].collectionOfPeople[0].name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what, if any, error messages you're getting but I believe in order to have

```
Town.People
```

you need to create a property of your Town class called People. I don't see that in your code.

Also, there's an extra parenthesis in your line:

```
txt_town.Text = townList[0].townName: //no ) after [0]
```

Comment: I'm attempting to display the List<People> collectionOfPeople; from within the Town class. When attempting Town.collectionOfPeople the error ;
Error 1 'TownDemo.Town.collectionOfPeople' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Thank you, the answer proved insightful!